# Using VS 2017 and VB to connect to a database

Tags: vb.net

First of, I am a beginner.
more clarification:
I am writing this program in Vis. Basic to access a database, get values and save the info.
the database is a MS Access 2016 database.
I have multiple forms and on each form different values are entered.
I now made an ADD form to write all the data from all the forms in my database.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String
        Dim custname, custnum, cgender, pkind, pmodel, probear, meduse, tint, tinl, crema, cneed As String
        Dim byear As Integer


        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Users\rolf\source\repos\AMEST_Audiology\AMEST_Audiology\bin\Debug\audiology.accdb"

        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()
        sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO audiodat (custName,Custnum,cgender,pkind,pmodel,probear,meduse,tint,tinl,crema,cneed) Values (@custName,@custnum,@cgender,@pkind,@pmodel,@probear,@meduse,@tint,@tinl,@crema,@cneed)"



        custname = FrmCust.custName
        custnum = FrmCust.Custnum
        cgender = FrmCust.CGender
        byear = FrmCust.byear
        pkind = FrmCust.pkind
        pmodel = FrmCust.pmodel
        probear = Frmhistory.probear
        meduse = Frmhistory.meduse
        tint = Frmhistory.tint
        tinl = Frmhistory.tinl
        crema = FrmClinic.crema
        cneed = Frmsolution.cneed




        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custname", custname)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custnum", custnum)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cgender", cgender)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pkind", pkind)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmodel", pmodel)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@probear", probear)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meduse", meduse)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tint", tint)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tinl", tinl)
        ' sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oprobhis", oprobhis)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crema", crema)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cneed", cneed)


        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try



    Frmprintdoc.Show()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

it works as far as the String goes, but i cant save numbers or checkbox state.
it also does NOT actually write the data into the database, just into the memory of the tableadapter. what am i missing???

Comment: Just a suggestion.. if you are just now learning the language and want to use .net, you will find a lot more people who can and will help you by targeting c# instead of VB.

Comment: When using MS Access database, be sure you're looking at the correct file when verifying results - it may be a copy located in your project's bin\Debug directory. Also make certain you have the UpdateCommand property of the TableAdapter properly setup. If it's empty or Nothing, then no updates will happen.